# How to operate a solenoid

Tags: solenoid

I purchased some of [these solenoids](http://www.ebay.com/itm/221814119793) and cannot get them to operate with a 12v battery. I am simply connecting the ground to one open wire and the positive to the other and the solenoid does not retract as I would expect. I also tried [using this power supply](http://www.banggood.com/EU-220V-DIY-LM317-Adjustable-Voltage-Power-Supply-Board-Kit-With-Case-p-973391.html), which causes the thing to shutdown when connected.

Is there something else I need to include to get these to work?

Comment: Apparently, neither the battery nor the power supply can supply the current required to make the thing work without bogging down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look more closely at your solenoid description. At 12 volts it will pull 8 amps! As it says, it is best used for impact applications, and they do not recommend using it for more than 2 seconds at a time, or it will get hot. And they're not kidding. 12 volts times 8 amps is 96 watts, so that is how much power it will dissipate, and that's how much power you must provide.

You don't say what kind of 12 volt battery you're using, but unless it's a car battery, it probably is not able to provide the current you need. Likewise, your power supply has no current rating, but its regulator is an LM317, and is not able to do better than about 1 amp.

So what you need is a much beefier power supply, or a much bigger battery.

Either way, don't apply power for more than about 2 seconds out of every 10 to 15 seconds, or you'll eventually damage the solenoid.

Comment: Just about to give the same answer. The power supply linked only has a power rating of 2W. So at 12V this is around 166mA - not enough for this solenoid.

Comment: Crap! I just ordered 8 of these for nothin. ;( I'm tired of learning through expensive mistakes.

Comment: @DigitalNinja - That was my thought, but the transformer looks big enough to do better, and so does the heat sink on the regulator. Plus, a single 2W figure doesn't make sense - low voltage/high current will dissipate a lot of heat in the regulator. For example, if the primary cap charges to 15 volts, 12 volts at 1 amp will only dissipate 3 W, but 3 volts at 1 amp will dissipate 12.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Good point. It probably can but still not suited for this solenoid.

Comment: @MichaelRader This is probably closer to what you want: http://www.adafruit.com/products/412?gclid=CKvtouWnp8cCFUyVfgodUQIJyQ and for about the same price.